In Qt, why calling a thread object's wait() function prevents it from receiving signal?
    QThread *ptr=new QThread();
    Worker *pwk=new Worker();
    ptr->setObjectName("Worker thread");
    pwk->moveToThread(ptr);
    QObject::connect(ptr,&QThread::started,pwk,&Worker::run);
    QObject::connect(pwk,&Worker::finished,ptr,[ptr](){
                    qInfo()<<"get finished signal to quit";
                    ptr->quit();});
    ptr->start();
    if(!ptr->wait(5000))
    {
        qInfo()<<ptr<<"is still running:"<<ptr->isRunning();
    }
    qInfo()<<"exit from"<<Q_FUNC_INFO;

The above code is executed in main thread. The signal Worker::finished has been emitted, which is verified by the execution of some pwk's slot function connected to the signal (not shown above) before the return of ptr->wait(5000). However, not until ptr->wait(5000) returns, does the ptr receive the finished signal. All connect calls return success. It seems that pwk's own functions are executed as normal while ptr's own event loop is not responding to event while ptr->wait is blocked.
What could be the possible reasons?

QObject::connect(pwk,&Worker::finished,ptr,[ptr](){
                    qInfo()<<"get finished signal to quit";
                    ptr->quit();},Qt::DirectConnection);

After I added Qt::DirectConnection, it works as expected.
I checked that pwk->thread() is of ptr, while ptr->thread is of main thread. So I believe that it is because the Qt uses queued connection to connect the sender pwk and receiver (main thread) by default, which sends the signal to the event loop of main thread. While the main thread is blocked by calling ptr->wait(), it can only respond to it after returning from the wait, and then calls the slot function ptr->quit().

There's no need to ask ChatGPT or try to make guesses. Just search and read the documentation: for instance, Signals and Slots Across Threads. Note, though, that you must very careful in using DirectConnection, because it causes the slot to be executed in the emitter thread, and if that slot is in a thread that deals with non-thread-safe objects (eg: widgets), that makes it quite risky.

ChatGPT content is strictly prohibited on Stack Overflow, even with attribution.
